# ggplot axis order criteria not in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this data frame that plots this heatmap:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

data.frame(id = factor(sample(1:100, 10000, replace=TRUE,
            prob = sample(1:9/10, 100, replace=TRUE)), levels = 1:100),
           year = factor(sample(1950:2019, 10000, replace=TRUE, 
            prob=sample(1:9/10, 70, replace=TRUE)), levels=1950:2019)) %>% 
unique() %>% arrange(id, year) %>% 
  mutate(flag = TRUE) %>% 
  complete(id, year, fill = list(flag = FALSE)) %>%
ggplot(aes(year, id, fill = flag)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

I need to order the ids from max FALSE count to minimum. I have tried this so far:

After the `complete()` function I added:

```
group_by(id, flag) %>%
mutate(order = ifelse(flag==FALSE, n(), NA)) %>%
```

and in the `ggplot()` line code:

```
ggplot(aes(year, reorder(id, order), fill = flag)) +
```

However, it still not working. I think it's because it has multiple order values for each id. How can I summarise the dataframe for ordering without messing with the dataframe for the plot? Or is there an easier way I'm not seeing?

Comment: ```... %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(order = sum(!flag))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)

data.frame(id = factor(sample(1:100, 10000, replace=TRUE,
                              prob = sample(1:9/10, 100, replace=TRUE)), levels = 1:100),
                  year = factor(sample(1950:2019, 10000, replace=TRUE, 
                              prob=sample(1:9/10, 70, replace=TRUE)), levels=1950:2019)) %>% 
        unique() %>% arrange(id, year) %>% 
        mutate(flag = TRUE) %>% 
        complete(id, year, fill = list(flag = FALSE)) %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        mutate(order = sum(!flag)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(year, reorder(id, order), fill = flag)) + 
        geom_tile()
```

[image]